Can you put a plastic barrier under planks in a raised bed?
Can you put plastic or fabric under planks in a raised bed to slow rotting of wood?

Plastic or fabric will actually increase the speed of any rot because the first is totally impermeable and will trap water against the sides while the second isn't very permeable itself and will have the same effect as plastic.
The best way to decrease rot in a bed used for vegetables is to use naturally rot-resistant wood such as cedar for the sides of the bed, with (assuming that the raised bed is not on legs) the bottom of the bed resting on bare soil. You could, if you wanted, drill weep holes at the very bottom of the side-boards to aid in drainage. If the bed is indeed on legs, then the bottom really must be made from rot-resistant wood.
If the raised bed will only hold ornamental and not edible plants, then you could use chemically treated wood for the entire planter.
UPDATED
It occurred to me that recycled plastic "lumber" could work as the planter's bottom, as long as you don't grow root vegetables in that planter OR if the planter is tall enough that the root vegetables won't come into contact with the planks.
Personally, I'm uneasy about introducing even more plastic (and who knows what other chemicals) into my body, but you're not me, so if you're comfortable with the idea of plastic near food, then you could also consider using that material for the entire planter box. This will eliminate all possibility of rot.
Another idea is to use silt fencing between the bottom planks to help keep the soilless mix in the planter. This is a much more porous material than fabric and is designed to let water through but not soil particles. You'll have to buy it with stakes attached - and it does take some work to remove them - but it lasts forever. But it's plastic!
